# JCombobox : implementation side effect?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I was going through docs for JCombobox, there are few methods with description

*This method is public as an implementation side effect.*

What does this mean?

Is it due to these method needs to be called from somewhere else and need to public but the implementation in those method shouldn't be public?

Comment: It's a side effect from having to implement a given interface. This is a general result of the classes been written before inner classes were supported

Answer (score 3):

The JComboBox class implements the interfaces of various event listeners (ActionListener, etc.).

Because the interfaces enforce public access, the JComboBox class defines those methods as public as well.

The comment is there to let developers know that they should not call these methods explicitly, even though they have public access.